# How to list all dictionaries from a module imported

Tags: python-3.x

mymodule.py:

```
STATES ={
    "Alabama": "AL",
    "Alaska" : "AK",
    "Arizona": "AZ"
}
CountryNr = {
    "Afghanistan": "93",
    "Albania"    : "355",
    "Algeria"    : "213"
}
```

from my python program, I can import this module:

```
import mymodule
```

My quesition is: how to list all the dictionaries? (PS; I have checked around none of the solutions work for me yet).

thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to have store them into a list or just print every dictionary in your module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the use case for this is, but I think you can use the `dir` function:

```py
import mymodule
dir(mymodule)
>> ['CountryNr', 'STATES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

If you want the content of the dictionaries I would suggest using the built-in inspect library:

```py
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(mymodule, lambda x: isinstance(x, dict))
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the simple `dir()` function; Next, the 1st child is what I would, i.e. `inspect.getmembers(mymodule, lambda x: isinstance(x, dict))[0]`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you only want the name of your dictionaries, so you could go with (extending Kevin's approach):

```
import mymodule
import inspect

dict_names = [name for name, value in inspect.getmembers(mymodule, lambda x: isinstance(x, dict)) if not name.startswith("__")]
```

`if not name.startswith("__")` is to exclude the `__builtins__`

This would return the following list: `['CountryNr', 'STATES']`